# Libre office stopped working on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice

Libreoffice stopped working on Ubuntu20.04.

When I try to open with the command line: libreoffice, it does not launch and returns the cryptic error message:

Libreoffice
Application Error

I have completely purged Libreoffice, and re-installed (several times).
The problem still persists.
Version used: LibreOffice 7.0.4.2
Same happens with LibreOffice 6.4.7.2.

Anyone can help?

EDIT: same happens with soffice --calc

Application Error

The logfile  for strace libreoffice7.0 --writer appears here:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/djtJFvR2rj/

Comment: Does this happen on all LO apps? Try this from the terminal - `soffice --calc` - and post the output (please add to your question)?

Comment: Thanks. Same happens: application error.

Comment: That's it? Nothing else? OK, try this: `soffice --safe-mode`.

Comment: Same error message: soffice --safe-mode
Application Error

Comment: Not sure what to try next. The only references I found were related to the Windows version. You might want to post this on https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/.

Comment: You might try running `strace soffice --writer` and then [edit your post](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1310660/edit) to include a [link to the pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) where you pasted the output from your terminal after running the command.